# Why are my stepUp/stepDown buttons submitting the form with each click

Tags: html

Not sure if it's the way my HTML is laid out or the way the `stepUp` / `stepDown` functions work, but for some reason clicking on the buttons automatically submits the form, stopping only if any other fields don't have valid inputs. Obviously this wouldn't be desired behavior for any form.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asa9ohan/1nr2g5zb/38/

```css
input[type="number"] {
    appearance: textfield;
    text-align: center;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

button {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="name-input">name <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="name-input" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="phone-num-input">phone number <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="phone-num-input" type="tel" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="email-input">email<br></label>
    <input id="email-input" type="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-field number-input">
    <label for="count-input">count<br></label>

    <div>
      <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#count-input').stepDown()" >-</button>
      <input id="count-input" min="0" value="0" type="number">
      <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#count-input').stepUp()" class="plus">+</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="inq-content-input">message <span>*</span><br></label>
    <textarea id="inq-content-input" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-form-button">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-form-submit">send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: buttons will try to submit the form on click. If you do not want to submit the form, then return false at the end of the onclick listener code. It indicates the button to stop submitting the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `return false` to your button scripts to avoid the buttons to submit the form:

```css
input[type="number"] {
    appearance: textfield;
    text-align: center;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

button {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="name-input">name <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="name-input" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="phone-num-input">phone number <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="phone-num-input" type="tel" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="email-input">email<br></label>
    <input id="email-input" type="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-field number-input">
    <label for="count-input">count<br></label>

    <div>
      <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#count-input').stepDown();return false" >-</button>
      <input id="count-input" min="0" value="0" type="number">
      <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#count-input').stepUp();return false" class="plus">+</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="inq-content-input">message <span>*</span><br></label>
    <textarea id="inq-content-input" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-form-button">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-form-submit">send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

A slightly "cleaner" approach would be the following:

```js
const cntr=document.getElementById("count-input");
document.querySelectorAll("button")
        .forEach((b,i)=>b.onclick=ev=>(i>2 || cntr[["stepDown","stepUp"][i]](),false) )
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
    appearance: textfield;
    text-align: center;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

button {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="name-input">name <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="name-input" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="phone-num-input">phone number <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="phone-num-input" type="tel" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="email-input">email<br></label>
    <input id="email-input" type="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-field number-input">
    <label for="count-input">count<br></label>

    <div>
      <button>-</button>
      <input id="count-input" min="0" value="0" type="number">
      <button>+</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="inq-content-input">message <span>*</span><br></label>
    <textarea id="inq-content-input" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-form-button">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-form-submit">send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out if I use div instead of button tags, it prevents the form from being submitted. I'd have to style the buttons independently, but the default button style would need restyling anyway.

```css
input[type="number"] {
    appearance: textfield;
    text-align: center;
  height: 1.5rem;
}
.number-input > div {
  display: flex;
}
.button {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  user-select: none;
}
.button:active { background: darkgray; }
```

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="name-input">name <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="name-input" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="phone-num-input">phone number <span>*</span><br></label>
    <input id="phone-num-input" type="tel" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="email-input">email<br></label>
    <input id="email-input" type="email">
  </div>

  <div class="form-field number-input">
    <label for="count-input">count<br></label>

    <div>
      <div onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#count-input').stepDown()" class="button minus">-</div>
      <input id="count-input" min="0" value="0" type="number">
      <div onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('#count-input').stepUp()" class="button plus">+</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="inq-content-input">message <span>*</span><br></label>
    <textarea id="inq-content-input" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-form-button">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-form-submit">send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```